# How to filter an array on the basis of field in php?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a php code as show below: 
    `$category = get_the_category();`  **//Line #A** 

 `echo '<pre>'; print_r($category); echo '</pre>';` **//Line #B**

The code at the 2nd line returns the following array;

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 13085
            [name] => Cannabis
            [slug] => democracy_project_cannabis
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 13085
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => Hello World 
            [parent] => 13083
            [count] => 8
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 13085
            [category_count] => 8
            [category_description] => Good Morning
            [cat_name] => Cannabis
            [category_nicename] => democracy_project_cannabis
            [category_parent] => 13083
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 13093
            [name] => Today
            [slug] => today
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 13093
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 13093
            [category_count] => 3
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Today
            [category_nicename] => today
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what php code I need to code so that it filters an array on the basis of **[name] => Today**. It should take only one field which is **[name] => Today**

I think I need to use `array_filter()` method but I am not sure how I can use it.

Comment: "The above code returns the following array;" How?

Comment: On doing `echo json_encode($cats);` it returns the array as mentioned in the question.

Comment: but it seems an **array of objects** so how you could do `echo` instead of `print_r()` ?

Comment: I saw an answer on SO and I used that in my code. Is it not right ?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Sorry, its my fault. I have edited the questiion.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Are you around ?

Comment: sorry sir, I was out, did you try my given solution? Is that helped?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If it is then have a look here :https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

With `array_filter()` and `use`, you'll get more flexibility while filtering multidimensional array by values

```
$filterBy = 'Today'; // any index value you want

$expected = array_filter($cats, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
    return ($var->name == $filterBy);
});

print_r($expected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an anonymous function that returns `true` if property `name == 'Today'` and `false` otherwise:

```
$result = array_filter($cats, function($v) { return $v->name == 'Today'; });
```

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: @john: Sometimes.

Comment: I have edited my question. There was a slight mistake in it.

Comment: The code at Line#A should take only  `[name] => Today`

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the result you expect. `get_the_category()` is a wordpress function and does only what it does.

Comment: Correct. Is there any way we can filter it by using `get_the_category()` as well ? I just want to take only `[name] => Today` `

Comment: Not with that function, there may be another but I don't use wordpress.